# For a random variable with distribution $P[|X| = i] = \frac{c}{i^2 \ln{i}}$, show that $nP[|X| \ge n] \to 0$

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Say $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integer-valued random variable distributed via the rule $P[X = i]= P[X = -i] = \frac{c}{i^2 \ln{i}}$ for $i = 3, 4, \dots$. Here, we have chosen $c$ so that

$$\sum_{i \le -3} \frac{c}{i^2 \ln{|i|}} + \sum_{i \ge 3} \frac{c}{i^2 \ln{i}} = 1.$$

We want to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} nP[|X| \ge n] = 0.$$

This question has been tough for me to handle. What I see so far is that $P[|X| \ge n]=\sum_{i \ge n} \frac{2c}{i^2 \ln{i}}$. Since the sum $\sum_{i \ge 3} \frac{2c}{i^2 \ln{i}}$ is convergent, the tails $\sum_{i \ge n} \frac{2c}{i^2 \ln{i}}$ certainly go to $0$. But the question I'm struggling with is how to show the tails go to $0$ fast enough to beat out that pesky factor of $n$.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technicality: In your first sum to the left of "$=1$ the $i$ in the $\ln{i}$ needs an absolute value sign around it.

Comment: Definitely. I'll fix that.

Comment: You need to demonstrate that $P[|X|\ge n]\lt\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, we need to estimate the tails. The double tail is $\lt \displaystyle\int_{n-1}^\infty k\dfrac{dx}{x^2\log x}$ for some constant $k$. Note that the double tail is therefore $\lt \dfrac{k}{\log(n-1)}\displaystyle\int_{n-1}^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x^2}$.

The integral $\displaystyle\int_{n-1}^\infty\dfrac{dx}{x^2}$ tames the pesky $n$, and the $\log(n-1)$ in the denominator provides the needed push to $0$.

Comment: But this double tail should be multiplied by $n$. That is, one wants to show that $n\cdot \int_{n+1}^{\infty}Kdx/(x^2 \log x)$ goes to zero.

Comment: @coffeemath: We have $\int_{n-1}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n-1}$. Multiply by $n$. The result is bounded, indeed close to $1$. But we are dividing by $\log(n-1)$ in front.

Comment: Yes! a good combination of one thing bounded and another going to zero. +1.